# distributionlibrary cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

I am trying to build OI shoppinglist that I imported from https://github.com/openintents/shoppinglist I imported it with git, then into eclipse and I'm getting errors like : distributionlibrary cannot be resolved to a type. This is my first attempt at downloading a project other than the ones in the developer.android.com examples. I searched the web and I'm kinda stuck any ideas?

Comment: It seems [they](http://openintents.org/en/shoppinglist) have an apk available for download, so you can just download that and then check with the source to figure out what's going on. Back to your question, did you download all the projects available?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am learning as I go on this one. When I imported the repository it expanded to /BarcodeScannerTest, /ShoppingActivity, ShoppingListLibrary are these the projects you speak of? I'm now searching for a way to open the apk for inspection but I get a lot of answers involving tools besides eclipse. Can anyone recomennd a tool to use or a way to use eclipse? I'm a total newbie to android development so a lot of basic details would be of great value.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, those projects are what I meant. Also, when I wrote _check with the source_ I didn't mean decompiling, I meant tracing the app. Eg, `y` executes and I see that on github there's a piece of code that executes `y`. Therefore, this is probably why `y` executed. A quick google search turns [this](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/branches/distributionlibrary/distribution/DistributionLibrary/src/org/openintents/distribution/DistributionLibrary.java?r=3055), it may be of use.

Comment: Ok I see what is missing. I should have found that one. Thanks!

Comment: Would you trace the app in the debugger?